# Set dynamic upload dir in jQuery Blueimp Upload Plugin?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'd like some help please. I have found this [wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Jquery-file-upload-8.8.5%2Cwith-codeigniter-2.1.x) in order to setup Blueimp Jquery Upload Plugin with CodeIgniter. Every thing works fine, but what I'd like to do is upload images on the appropriate album-directories.

This is my code in the controller

```
public function upload(){
// get the album directory in order to upload images to the correct album
$id = $this->input->post('album');
        $album = $this->album_model->get_album_dir($id);

// now I need pass the album directory to the UploadHandler, 
// in order to specify the correct upload path
        $this->load->library('UploadHandler');
    }
```

and this is the main code for settings inside UploadHandler

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/admin/upload',
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/uploads/albums/' . <PUT-ALBUM-DIRECTORY-HERE>,
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/uploads/albums/' . . <PUT-ALBUM-DIRECTORY-HERE>,
```

**UPDATE**: This is my code in controller

```
public function upload(){
        // get the album directory in order to upload images to the correct album
    $id = $this->input->post('album');
            $album = $this->album_model->get_album_dir($id);


        $options = array(
            'script_path' => '/admin/upload',
            'upload_dir' => '/uploads/albums/'. $album,
            'upload_url' => '/uploads/albums/'. $album,
            'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i',
        );
        $this->load->library('UploadHandler', $options);
    }
```

and this is the code inside UploadHandler.php

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {

        $script_url = isset($options['script_path']) ? $options['script_path'] : '/';
        $upload_dir = isset($options['upload_dir']) ? $options['upload_dir'] : '/files/';
        $upload_url = isset($options['upload_url']) ? $options['upload_url'] : '/files/';
        $accept_file_types = isset($options['accept_file_types']) ? $options['accept_file_types'] : '/.+$/i' ;

        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->get_full_url(). $script_url,
            'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')). $upload_dir,
            'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url(). $upload_url,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the [Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) you can pass parameters to library while initializing.

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');

$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
```

so in your case it should be

```
    $album = $this->album_model->get_album_dir($id);
    $options= array("upload_dir"=>'dir here',"upload_url"=>'url here');
    $this->load->library('UploadHandler',$options); // you can set the options of Upload handler
```

now in `upload_handler.php`

```
'upload_dir' => if(isset($options['upload_dir'])) ? $options['upload_dir'] : "default dir for all",
'upload_url' => if(isset($options['upload_url'])) ? $options['upload_url'] : "default url for all",
```

**Note** : you can do further test instead of just isset.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but when I pass $options in $this->load->library('UploadHandler', $options), they don't seem to append to the $this->options = array() ( in the __construct() ).

Comment: @Lykos you need to update `upload_handler.php` as mentioned in the answer

Comment: I did an update on the code, as you said, but not working. please review.

Comment: in `$this->options = array` set `'script_url' = > $script_url` and smae for `upload_dir` , `upload_url` etc.

Comment: I think these variables need to append on $this->get_full_url(), dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')) etc  in order to get the full path correct.